# tcpdump filter for tcp zero window messages

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump, pcap

Is there a pcap filter for TCPDump that will allow be to filter zero window messages?

I know how to filter these in a wireshark display filter (`tcp.analysis.zero_window`) but the amount of data I need to work with easily crashes wireshark (at least the 32 bit version) and breaking up the file and going through those captures is tedious.

Is there anyway to have a capture filter for TCP Zero Window Messages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it can be done using a filter like:

```
"tcp[14] = 0 && tcp[15] = 0"
```

The `tcp[i]` notation means the index `i` of TCP header. The window size is located after 14 bytes from TCP header. For more info, you can look at `man pcap-filter`.

Comment: You can also match both bytes directly: `tcp[14:2] = 0`.